# org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='my_tbl'

Tags: java, spring

I am using DBUnit and Spring Test DBUnit to initialise my database into a known state for testing purposes.

I have a my_tbl table in my H2 DB (as in memory db for ubit test.).

```
--schema.sql
CREATE TABLE my_tbl(
[name] character varying(255) NOT NULL,
`type` character varying(255) NOT NULL,
language character varying(255) NOT NULL,
some_text character varying(255),
modified_by character varying(255),
modified_date date,
predefined integer DEFAULT 0
);

-- jdbc.test.properties
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sbsdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=


<!-- Unit Test environment -->

<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath*:/jdbc.test.properties" />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource"
        ignore-failures="ALL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/h2/schema.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <bean id="datatypeFactory" class="org.dbunit.ext.h2.H2DataTypeFactory" />
    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
        <property name="datatypeFactory" ref="datatypeFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection"
        class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

While performing Unit testing I am getting following Exception.

```
org.dbunit.DatabaseUnitException: Exception processing table name='my_tbl'
at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:231)
at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:162)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:60)
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:160)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:358)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
 ......................................................
```

I suspect that it's column named type which is creating problem. though I used `` to quote as suggested on many forums. But that's not working for me.  I don't understand the reason why it's happening like that. Please help.

Best Regards,
Maneesh Saxena

Comment: I forgot to mention that type is reserved keyword for h2 db. That's the reason why it can't be used as column name without quoting it in ``.

Comment: Nice question for a newbie, too bad you didn't hear back on it.